# How to add button group instead radio button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to ad button group instead radio button.. there is three buttons. all three buttons are same color(blue). when user click on 1st button it will change that button color as red. But when user click on second button, first button must turn into blue color and clicked button(2nd button) must turn in to red. In my code that's not change. Help me

```
    <Button Background="#0D47A1" Command="{Binding LanguageChangeCommand}" CommandParameter="Sinhala" Content="සිංහල" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Height="37" Width="81">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#2E8B57"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
    <Button Command="{Binding LanguageChangeCommand}" Background="#0D47A1" CommandParameter="English" Content="English" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,15,0,0" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#2E8B57"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
    <Button Command="{Binding LanguageChangeCommand}" Background="#0D47A1" CommandParameter="Tamil" Content="தமிழ்" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="215,15,0,0" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#DDFDF9F9">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#2E8B57"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Button Group? Another idea is `ListBox` with styled `ListBoxItem`.

```
<ListBox VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="border"
                                Padding="3" Background="SkyBlue"
                                BorderBrush="DeepSkyBlue" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="OrangeRed" />
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="HotPink" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBoxItem Content="1" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="2" IsSelected="True" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="3" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="4" />
</ListBox>
```

[image]

The benefit of `ListBox` is that you can use binding and easily to get the value of selected "button" by the user.

Comment: thank you very much sir you are amaizing

Comment: please can you explain me how to bind and how to add a command parameter foe each list box item